# Pharisees and name of God

Tags: names

I know the Scribes aka Sadducee (Heb. sōperêm, writers) had a habit of removing holy names from the scriptures but did the Pharisee also refuse to use God's personal name?

Comment: Hi SamTzu and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Could you clarify what you mean regarding both clauses of your question by adding more detail and sources?

Comment: Did Pharisee' use God's personal name (JHWH or some version of that) in everyday life?

Comment: Saducees are tzedukim. As far as I know, sophrim are not a sect. I'm also not clear on this concept of "God's personal name".

Comment: God does not have a name.

Comment: @Turk Hill - Moses would disagree with you.

Comment: @SamTzu No, Moses would agree with me.

Comment: @TurkHill No, G-d, blessed be He, explicitly states His name(s). And don't speak in the name of Moses or someone else.

Comment: @setszu I didn't speak in the name of Moses. I just said he would agree with me that God has no name like Joe.

Comment: @TurkHill That's projecting your words onto Moses. And like I said, G-d, blessed be He, explicitly states His Holy Name.

Comment: @setszu God stated his name only if you believe God has vocal cords to say it.

Comment: @TurkHill Why do you assume that that's the only way G-d, blessed be He, can "speak"?

Comment: @setszu How else would he "speak?"

Comment: @all - Guys let's not make this a bar fight but rather more like a scientific paper or legal issue where facts are required with references. I'm refering to Exodus 4:10. (https://biblehub.com/interlinear/exodus/4-10.htm) If some1 claims that does not count I'm going to ask for proof.

Answer (score 3):

The Tetragrammaton was only pronounced once a year by the High Priest in the Yom Kippur Service in the times *before* the Pharisees (how far back is out of scope for this question), and not in every day life. Other than that, once every seven years the pronouncement was taught to a select Sage in order to preserve it.

Our tradition indicates that Shimon Hatzaddik's brother ended these practices. This was about 100 years before the establishment of the Pharisees, so there was no pronouncement of the name during their time. Source: Guide for the Perplexed 1:61-62.

This does not mean that the Pharisees censored the *writing* of the name in Torah and prayer scrolls, just the pronouncement. It was written then, and it is written now, and we still don't pronounce it. Rather, we say "Adon-ai", "My Lord".

Comment: I believe we have instances in scripture of lots of people using the divine name (even non Israelites) before the exile. So I'm not sure how truthful your answer is

Comment: @Aaron bring them

Comment: Balaam uses it in NUmbers 22, Rahab uses it before her conversion in Joshua 2, Pharoah says "I don't know [the name]" and Naaman the Syrian general in Second Kings 5:22 off the top of my head

Comment: @Aaron thanks. None of these are Pharisees, but I will make a small adjustment to include these possibilities further back in time.

Comment: @Aaron Having it written out isn't a proof that they pronounced it.  I have siddurim in my house with it written out too, but that doesn't mean I pronounce it.

Comment: @Heshy They are quoting people speaking. Seems weird to me they would put in words they never spoke

Comment: @Aaron The quotes are also in Hebrew. Do you think all of those figures you mentioned spoke Hebrew? The Torah isn’t quoting verbatim, necessarily.

Comment: @ezra Sometimes the Torah makes it clear people are speaking Aramaic. Sometimes the Torah makes it clear there is translation happening. If it seems like someone shouldn't be able to speak Hebrew, I assume translation is happening. But for example, it's possible that people in Canaan spoke Hebrew so Rahab was probably speaking Hebrew directly or if not then probably Aramaic

Comment: @ezra 2 kings 18:19-26 Rab-shakeh of Assyria speaks to the Judeans in Hebrew and uses the Tetragrammaton and literally Eliakim on the wall asks them to speak in Aramaic so that way other Judeans won't understand what's being said. I don't know how more direct you can get

Comment: @Kaii - "not in every day life." Thank you. This is the kind of information I'm searching for. I'm a Northman from "way up north" (barbaricum) and our genealogies only go back a few generations. We don't have much of a culture so I'm not burdent by it. I'm much more interested in facts than customs. My question rose after I watched the new series "Chosen" and noticed that even though it mentions "Lords Prayer" several times it fails to "Hollow" His name. I'm still kind of confused by how the "Goverments" worked at the time.

Comment: @Aaron "_They are quoting people speaking. Seems weird to me they would put in words they never spoke_", this reminds me of a question a friend of mine often asks me in our discussions "do you think King Pharaoh really spoke Lashon Hakodesh when he's being quoted? What do you think?

Comment: @SamTzu I didn't understand your last comment, sorry. If there was a question, feel free to restate it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well I'll be able to source this answer as it's a general read of the entire Bible. But it appears from scripture that a lot shifts after the Babylonian exile. We don't hear much about scribes, or public reading of the Torah before the exile. We also see a significant drop in people using the tetragrammaton after the Babylonian exile.

Before the Babylonian exile, Israelites and non Israelites seem to freely use the divine name. Moses tells Pharoah he and the Israelites want to go worship a God called Y-H-W-H and Pharoah says he doesn't know that God. Balaam the prophet tells it to the Midianite messengers in Numbers 22. Rahab the prostitute already knows the divine name and tells it to the Israelite spies in Joshua 2. Naaman the Syrian general uses it with the prophet Elishah in 2 Kings 5:22. The list can go on and on.

But after the exile we see a whole new level of religiosity and classes of people such as Ezra the scribe. Suddenly we can't intermingle with the Samaritans and we have to be separate from them. Now for the first time we are instituting public readings of scripture for Holidays and it's not clear the people hearing it have heard these words before. And if I had to guess, the censoring of the divine name started with Ezra and these public readings. And my further guess would be that both Pharisees and Sadduccees would inherit their traditions from here.

Note: This answer is opinion based and unsourced.